# Asterisk ARI initiating a call

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari, asternet

I am trying to initiate a call between two local endpoints, a **softphone(PJSIP/100)** and a **harphone(PJSIP/102)**. Using ARI I have created two channels, with app parameters and put them both into the same mixing bridge in stasisStart event.

At this moment, both of the channels are in the same bridge, but their state is "Down". If I now dial both of them separately from ARI and then press answer on both endpoints, they can share audio, but is it possible to avoid dialing and answering both of them? I have played around the "originator" and "callerid" parameters, which is passed when creating channels, but that does not help.

Is it possible to "dial" one of them from another via ARI?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not 100% clear what you’re trying to do here, but from what I understand...
Dial PJSIP/100 and put it into bridge_1 in statisStart
Dial PJSIP/102 and put it into bridge_1 in stasisStart

You could dial them using stasis originate or an originate via the dialplan.